# Graph $S$ and its image $f(S)$

Tags: complex-analysis, graphing-functions, euler-mascheroni-constant

$$S=\{z: -1<Re(z)<2\}$$
$$w=f(z)=e^z$$

Graph $S$ and $f(S)= \{w\}=\{f(z)\mid z \in S\}$

**My attempt:**

[This is what I think it should look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hd6tr.jpg) Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think the general concept is that when graphing $z$ you do it based on any constraints of $x$ and $y$. For $w$ you graph the function $f(z)$ but *still keeping in mind the previous constraints of $x$ or $y$.* Is this on the right track?

**Update:**
[This is what I came up with based on an answer given.](http://m.imgur.com/HyQKFYn) If we write $e^z$ in terms of $x$ and $y$, and also limit the $x$ based on the constraint given, then the resulting image of $f(S)$ should be an open disc that does not include $r=1/e$ or $r=e^2$.

Answer (score 1):

The set $S$ is the points of the plane with real part between $-1$ and $2$.  I believe your sketch is a perfectly reasonable representation of this set.

The set $f(S)$ is a little different...

Let $s \in S$.  You know $\Re(s) \in (-1,2)$ (that's "the real part of s is in $(-1,2)$").  So if we write $s = x + \mathrm{i} y$, we know $-1 < x < 2$.  But $y$ can be anything.  So let's pick a real part, say $1/2$ and let the imaginary part wave around.  We want to know what figure we get from $f(1/2 + \mathrm{i} y) = \mathrm{e}^{1/2 + \mathrm{i} y} = \sqrt{\mathrm{e}} \cdot \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} y}$.  The $\sqrt{\mathrm{e}}$ is the magnitude of the point and the $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} y}$ gives an angle ($\arg$).  But that means the line $\Re(s) = 1/2$ gives the circle of radius $\mathrm{e}^{1/2}$.

What does that mean the other choices of real part give us?

What do we get when we glue all those figures together?

Comment: I think I understand. I've updated my question based on your reasoning. Is it on the right track?

Comment: Looking at your now photograph.  Umm...  "Less than" doesn't make any sense in the complex numbers.  You probably mean $|this| < |that|$, generally.  $\mathrm{e}^{-1} \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} y} \neq \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} y}$.  It's $\mathrm{e}^{-1} \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} y} = \mathrm{e}^{-1 + \mathrm{i} y}$.  You shouldn't be mixing the real an imaginary parts in the way you have.  Your graph shows an inner radius of $1$ and an outer radius of $8$.  It would be better to label it with the numbers you mean, "$1/\mathrm{e}$" and "$\mathrm{e}^2$".